# Freeswitch's `mod_dingaling` Google Voice authentication failure

Tags: freeswitch

Does anyone currently have a working setup of Google Voice calling with Freeswitch? I have had one working before for many years (as per https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Google_Voice) but now am receiving following error message:

```
 [CRIT] libdingaling.c:1675 sasl authentication failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google dropped xmpp support, for more details please check following link:

http://nerdvittles.com/?p=9286